# Retrieving Image Path in android studio

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am working on an android application. It has a functionality that captured image should display on screen and I need to get that image path, so that I can send that image to server.

Here is my code :

```
 private void takePhoto(View v) {

        Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
        photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"pictures.jpg");


        imageUri=Uri.fromFile(photo);
       intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent,TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
```

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==TAKE_PICTURE)
        {
        if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK) {


            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();

        try {
                    //Adding Image Attachment to email
           String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            attachmentFile = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
            URI = Uri.parse("file://" + attachmentFile);
            cursor.close();

                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "PhotoShoot Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
  catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Could not Complete Please Try Again.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
            }
```

Currently the format of path is :

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/pictures.jpg`

I want to have path of format : 
`content://media/external/images/media/34826`

When I try replacing

`Uri selectedImage = imageUri;`

by

`Uri selectedImage = data.getData();`

For required content, "data" contains a null value.

Comment: `want to have path of format : content://media/external/images/media/34826`. Why?

Comment: `When I try replacing`... Why would you? You have already your uri.

Comment: `need to get that image path`. Well that is photo.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: I want to have the format of that type for sending it to mail activity as an attachment.

Comment: Just a normal path on the file system would do. So I don't understand why you want a content format.

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I send it as an attachment without path in content format?Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well it would be nearly the same as with an Uri. So show your code to begin with.